# select id number from visible element

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have like this:

```
<div id="a1">test</div>
<div id="a2">thest</div>
```

the 'id's starting with `a` are a lot and css for one `a` is visible and others are hidden and now I want to get the number for visible id like this

```
var idz = $('[id^=a]:visible').attr('id');
var idv = parseInt(idz, 10);
```

But seems wrong. How can I do?

Comment: By logging idz, the error should have been obvious. It might look like you didn't debug a lot before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case `idz` will be `a1`, you need to first get the numeric portion form this, for that you can use [String.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```
var idz = $('[id^=a]:visible').attr('id');
var idv = parseInt(idz.substring(1), 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regexp

```
var idz = $('[id^=a]:visible').attr('id').match(/\d+/)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var idget = $('div[id^=a]:visible').attr('id');
var idvalue = parseInt(idget .substring(1), 10);
```

reference **[subString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)**